# Convert MySQL time to standard time with AM and PM

Tags: php, mysql, time

Having trouble converting AM time values from MySQL fetch_array when using the PHP date() function. Not sure why the stop time below is being printed as the 7:00PM when it should be 11:00AM. Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated!

```
<?php
$mysql_output = array('start' => '19:00:00','stop' => '11:00:00');

$start_time = date('g:iA',$mysql_output['start']);
$stop_time = date('g:iA',$mysql_output['stop']);

echo "<p>start_time: $start_time</p>";
echo "<p>stop_time: $stop_time</p>";
?>
```

The result doesn't convert the AM time correctly; should read **11:00AM** for **stop_time**:

```
start_time: 7:00PM
stop_time: 7:00PM
```

Comment: Is the 19:00:00 the exact data you are getting back from the database?

Comment: Yes, the field type is set to 'time' in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `date()` function takes a Unix timestamp, not a string datetimestamp. You need to put a MySQL datetimestamp through `strtotime()` first.

```
$start_time = date('g:iA', strtotime($mysql_output['start']));
$stop_time = date('g:iA', strtotime($mysql_output['stop']));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want mysql to convert it for you, just use the [**DATE_FORMAT( )**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6861a/5)

Answer (score 0):

The date function is misinterpreting your data.

You should create a time object first, then pass that in as a parameter to date.